# Hangman working the opposite way[Python 3]

Tags: python

I am following a python tutorial, and I am making a game of Hangman.

I am given the source code for the game, And that is *exactly* what I have put in my program. But it's not working as expected. It doesn't crash, but for every **correct** letter that is in the word, The player is hung up further, and it is put it in the list of missed letters. But for every **wrong** letter, that ISN'T in the word, I am not hung up further and neither does the letter go in the correct letters, neither the missed letters. I checked it line by line with the source code, and it matches, so now i officially have no idea what is wrong.

PLEASE NOTE: I CAN'T GET THE CODE FORMATTING TO WORK, SO FOR NOW, HERE ARE SOME SCREEN SHOTS. i'LL UPLOAD THE CODE ASAP.

[part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4utgN.png)

[part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT9wZ.png)

[continuation of the long string from part 2 and part three in the comments or as answer, i don't have reputation enough.........]

as i said, i'll add the real code as soon as i can.

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of answering below if you do not have an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend uploading the code rather than showing screenshots of the code. Either add the code to the post or upload it to a paste-bin like website that supports code syntax highlighting.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @user254948 okay, I'll do that if needed next time.

Comment: @cricket_007 I doon't have enough reputation to embed the photos and to add more than two links. So I had to post the links in an answer.

Comment: I understand, but if you had taken the time to get the resources available to post the actual code instead of rushing the screenshots, we wouldn't be telling you these things, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation for else statement after you start your game loop.

```
if guess in secretWord:
    # Your code
else:
    missedLetters = missedLetters + guess
```

Comment: Oh okay, thank you.